# android - How to remove element from array ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a random , which repeatedly selects one ImageButton from the array. Since the rand may select the same item several times , it is necessary to remove the second choice from the array element selected in the first randomness. Is this possible with the InageButtons array? Here is my code...

```
Random random = new Random();
ImageButton buttons[] = { labirint11, labirint12, labirint13, labirint14, labirint15, labirint16, labirint17, labirint18, labirint19 };
int choice = random.nextInt(buttons.length);

if (buttons[choice]==v) { 
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_wall); 
} else {
    buttons[choice].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_wall);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.door_go);
}
```

Comment: Remove as in delete an array element? If so, use an ArrayList instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array.  Arrays are tedious to resize and shift elements, but ArrayList does it for you.  See the [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

@dsh suggestion is great. You can also use [Sparse Array](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) which does not shift
elements on delete

**example**

```
SparseArray<ImageButton> buttons = new SparseArray<>(10);
buttons.put(0, imageButton0);
buttons.put(1, imageButton1);
...

buttons.remove(0);
buttons.removeAt(index);
```

Comment: please, help me. I use your code. Error: length. Write full code for my situation. Sorry, little english